# Jquery Script not working in any browsers but firefox?

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I have this script that is very simple it's used to create a simple slide, it works as expected in firefox but in any other browsers one or two things fails, and i can't really see why it does behave like this. The page can be seen here http://phonecover.se/lionbar/
The effect can be seen if you press one of the menu buttons but it will only work in firefox.
All help is very much appreciated 
Regards

Comment: The page can be seen, but what particular *script* is causing the problem? Could you post a demo reproducing the problem [on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and, ideally, *explain* what's supposed to happen, what *isn't* happening and any errors reported by the other, non-Firefox, browsers?

Comment: You should post some code, it's not exactly easy rooting out your problem from just a link.

Comment: if u press the menu in firefox the content will slide but it doesnt in any other browser ive tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your script has an error on this line:

```
var mov = -slval+plval.left;
```

as slval is a string containing "au".  Do you mean to instead do:

```
var mov = "-"+slval+plval.left
```

?

Comment: thx though it lead me to find the error, by not defining left it read it as auto, which made the calculations fail ofc, by setting the left positioning to 0 it got solved

Comment: @Breezer: I just found that error, but when I started tracking the reason for that no CSS rules seemed to apply to any element, and when I reloaded the page there was a `left` style, and it was working...